# Why is PayPal's sample Orders API code generating errors in my ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, paypal, webforms, paypal-sandbox

**EDIT:  Here is a Dropbox link that provides an 8-minute procedure for recreating my problem using PayPal's original C# code (it generates the same errors as I found when using a VB.NET conversion of that code). All you need is Visual Studio.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/53phlxny755h560/PayPal%20Orders%20API%20software%20problem.docx?dl=0**

I am trying for the first time to implement a PayPal Checkout solution in an ASP.NET Web Application, using Web Forms. I set up a new REST API for the Sandbox and followed PayPal's Set up server-side SDK guidance to install the SDK in my .NET project. Using the sample script provided on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/integrate/, I created a PayPalButton.aspx page that displays PayPal's buttons and lets me make a test payment (using my Sandbox ClientID). So far, so good.

With that simple client-side demo now working, I moved on to creating server-side code based on the samples provided at the following two pages: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/create-order/ https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/capture-order/. The C# code for .NET provided on those links was converted to VB.NET using the Telerik converter and copied into two new pages, **PayPalCreateOrder.vb** and **PayPalCaptureOrder.vb**.

Visual Studio displayed a lot of wavy red lines on these new pages and suggested that I should install the System.Net.Http package using the NuGet Package Manager. That fixed many of the problems. The remaining problems are the reason for this post.

My PayPalCreateOrder.vb code is shown below and this is preceded by several Imports statements, including 'Imports PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders'. Despite this, the code *Dim response = Await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request)* in the Createorder function has a wavy red line under PayPalClient, which VS 2019 says is not declared.

There are also wavy red lines under several words in the BuildRequestBody function. VS 2019 tells me that Intent is not a member of 'OrderRequest', Amount is not a member of 'PurchaseUnitRequest', Breakdown is not a member of 'AmountWithBreakdown', Shipping is not a member of 'PurchaseUnitRequest', and ShippingDetails is not defined.

I'm a bit lost here. Some assistance would be much appreciated.

```
Public Class CreateOrderSample
Public Shared Async Function CreateOrder(ByVal Optional debug As Boolean = False) As Task(Of HttpResponse)
    Dim request = New OrdersCreateRequest()
    request.Prefer("return=representation")
    request.RequestBody(BuildRequestBody())
    Dim response = Await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request)

    If debug Then
        Dim result = response.Result(Of Order)()
        Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", result.Status)
        Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", result.Id)
        Console.WriteLine("Intent: {0}", result.Intent)
        Console.WriteLine("Links:")

        For Each link As LinkDescription In result.Links
            Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "{0}: {1}" & vbTab & "Call Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method)
        Next

        Dim amount As AmountWithBreakdown = result.PurchaseUnits(0).Amount
        Console.WriteLine("Total Amount: {0} {1}", amount.CurrencyCode, amount.Value)
    End If

    Return response
End Function

Private Shared Function BuildRequestBody() As OrderRequest
    Dim orderRequest As OrderRequest = New OrderRequest() With {
            .Intent = "CAPTURE",
            .ApplicationContext = New ApplicationContext With {
                .BrandName = "EXAMPLE INC",
                .LandingPage = "BILLING",
                .UserAction = "CONTINUE",
                .ShippingPreference = "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS"
            },
            .PurchaseUnits = New List(Of PurchaseUnitRequest) From {
                New PurchaseUnitRequest With {
                    .ReferenceId = "PUHF",
                    .Description = "Sporting Goods",
                    .CustomId = "CUST-HighFashions",
                    .SoftDescriptor = "HighFashions",
                    .Amount = New AmountWithBreakdown With {
                        .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                        .Value = "230.00",
                        .Breakdown = New AmountBreakdown With {
                            .ItemTotal = New Money With {
                                .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                .Value = "180.00"
                            },
                            .Shipping = New Money With {
                                .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                .Value = "30.00"
                            },
                            .Handling = New Money With {
                                .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                .Value = "10.00"
                            },
                            .TaxTotal = New Money With {
                                .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                .Value = "20.00"
                            },
                            .ShippingDiscount = New Money With {
                                .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                .Value = "10.00"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    .Items = New List(Of Item) From {
                        New Item With {
                            .Name = "T-shirt",
                            .Description = "Green XL",
                            .Sku = "sku01",
                            .UnitAmount = New Money With {
                                .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                .Value = "90.00"
                            },
                            .Tax = New Money With {
                                .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                .Value = "10.00"
                            },
                            .Quantity = "1",
                            .Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                        },
                        New Item With {
                            .Name = "Shoes",
                            .Description = "Running, Size 10.5",
                            .Sku = "sku02",
                            .UnitAmount = New Money With {
                                .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                .Value = "45.00"
                            },
                            .Tax = New Money With {
                                .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                .Value = "5.00"
                            },
                            .Quantity = "2",
                            .Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                        }
                    },
                    .Shipping = New ShippingDetails With {
                        .Name = New Name With {
                            .FullName = "John Doe"
                        },
                        .AddressPortable = New AddressPortable With {
                            .AddressLine1 = "123 Townsend St",
                            .AddressLine2 = "Floor 6",
                            .AdminArea2 = "San Francisco",
                            .AdminArea1 = "CA",
                            .PostalCode = "94107",
                            .CountryCode = "US"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    Return orderRequest
End Function

Private Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
    CreateOrder(True).Wait()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Update your question with the complete code. Do you have `Imports PayPalCheckoutSdk.Core`, 
`Imports PayPalHttp`

Comment: Stackoverflow's code tool couldn't cope with the inclusion of my Imports statements, which is why they aren't listed. It does import PayPalHttp. It also imports PayPalCheckoutSdk.Core, though VS 2019 greys it out as being unnecessary.

Comment: @Preston PHX Here is a Dropbox link to a document that describes how to recreate this problem:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/53phlxny755h560/PayPal%20Orders%20API%20software%20problem.docx?dl=0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069605/preston-phx

Comment: Sorry, still getting to grips with how I alert you of my updates via a comment. Aftter reading the instructions (!), I think this should work:
@Preston

Comment: @preston-phx 
The Dropbox document that shows how to recreate my problem has now been updated and simplified. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/53phlxny755h560/PayPal%20Orders%20API%20software%20problem.docx?dl=0

Comment: @PrestonPHX - I don't think my previous attempts to alert you that I had responded to your original comment were correctly formatted, so this is another attempt to attract your attention. Your past assistance has been very useful to me and is much appreciated.